# In newly created column, use value in row above to calculate next row using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a data frame like the one below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df <- tibble(t = 1:3, a = c(4, 6, 11), b = 1:3, c = c(1, 3, 2))

df
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#       t     a     b     c
#   <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1     1     4     1     1
# 2     2     6     2     3
# 3     3    11     3     2
```

I want to calculate a new column `d` such that

> d(0) = a
>
> d(t) = d(t-1) + b(t-1) + c(t-1)

I can do this (painfully) with a for loop:

```
for_loop <- add_column(df, d = 0)
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if(i == 1) {
    for_loop[i,]$d <- for_loop[i,]$a
  }
  else {
    for_loop[i,]$d <- for_loop[i-1,]$d + for_loop[i-1,]$b + for_loop[i-1,]$c
  }
}
for_loop
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#       t     a     b     c     d
#   <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     4     1     1     4
# 2     2     6     2     3     6
# 3     3    11     3     2    11
```

But I want to do it using dplyr. Trying a simple ifelse doesn't seem to work, because the calculation is vectorized, so the old values of `d` are used:

```
tidy <- add_column(df, d = 0) %>%
  mutate(tidy, d = ifelse(row_number(d)==1, a, lag(d) + lag(b) + lag(c)))
tidy
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#       t     a     b     c     d
#   <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     4     1     1     4
# 2     2     6     2     3     2
# 3     3    11     3     2     5
```

**How can I use a previous value of `d` to calculate a new value of `d` using dplyr?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `cumsum` on lagged `b+c` and then add the initial value `a[1]` to the result:

```
df %>% mutate(d = a[1] + cumsum(lag(b + c, default = 0)))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
#      t     a     b     c     d
#  <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     4     1     1     4
#2     2     6     2     3     6
#3     3    11     3     2    11
```

---

In order to vectorize it, you need to eliminate the previous `d` (*d[t-1]*) from your formula like follows:

```
d[t] = d[t-1] + b[t-1] + c[t-1]  
     = d[t-2] + b[t-2] + c[t-2] + b[t-1] + c[t-1]
     = d[1] + 0 + b[1] + b[2] + ... + b[t-1] + 0 + c[1] + c[2] + ... + c[t-1]
     = a[1] + sum(lag(b + c, default=0))

d = a[1] + cumsum(lag(b + c, default = 0))
```

Comment: Fantastic. I didn't know you could combine cumsum and lag like that.